# Copying a directory in Java

Tags: java, exception, io, copy

Basically reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) tutorial, I have come across a bit in which it explains how to use the REPLACE_EXISTING StandardCopyOption.

> REPLACE_EXISTING – Performs the copy even when the target file already
> exists. If the target is a symbolic link, the link itself is copied
> (and not the target of the link). If the target is a non-empty
> directory, the copy fails with the FileAlreadyExistsException
> exception.

At the end of the bit I quoted, it says "**If the target is a non-empty directory, the copy fails with the FileAlreadyExistsException exception.**"
Actually I have tried it and it does not give me any exception, I tried to copy a non-empty folder from a location to the Desktop and it succeeded without giving me the FileAlreadyExistsException that in theory I should have got.

Is it something regular?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

Create:

```
C:\map1\fileA.txt
C:\map2\fileB.txt
```

Move:

```
C:\map1 to C:\map2
Files.copy(
        (new File("C:\map1")).toPath(), 
        (new File("C:\map2")).toPath(), 
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

This results in:

```
C:\map1\fileA.txt
C:\map2\fileB.txt
```

Why?:

"Directories can be copied. However, files inside the directory are not copied, so the new directory is empty even when the original directory contains files."

As mentioned by your reference.

**DirectoryNotEmptyException** - the REPLACE_EXISTING option is specified but the file cannot be replaced because it is a non-empty directory (optional specific exception)

**FileAlreadyExistsException** - if the target file exists but cannot be replaced because the REPLACE_EXISTING option is not specified (optional specific exception)

[Source.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29)

Comment: Ah ok i did not capture that details, I am going to try asap

Comment: I did as you said and I got  IOExceptionjava.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException:                     I am using jdk 1.7.

Comment: Which `StandardCopyOption` did you use for this test?

Comment: Will run some tests as soon as I'm home :)

Comment: Also on some platforms (maybe just Windows), copy/move can fail even if the file exists, even if REPLACE_EXISTING is specified.